# Where can I find examples of Game Mechanics?

Tags: mechanics, prototyping

I'm prototyping a game, but I'm not very schooled on board games. I'm looking for a list of game mechanics so that I can

1. Describe my game in terms of mechanics
2. Find other uses of the mechanics to learn from
3. Pick and choose what mechanics I want to have in my game.

(If there are any books about this sort of thing it would be freaking awesome!)

---

This is similar to some other questions, but with some differences:

- [What set of attributes can be used to describe, compare and contrast various board games?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2682) - but I need only the mechanics, not whether it is easy to carry etc.
- [Board Game Mechanics](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/board-game-mechanics) - nice question, but the answers with examples of games people likes, are not very helpful (I don't have access to the games or the time to understand them all).

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I've reworded your question a bit to not directly ask for the list, but to ask how to find it.  We'd rather not host endless lists here at stack exchange but prefer hosting information that specifically solves problems.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You probably should go looking at the various mechanic lists on boardgamegeek.com.

Examine the various reviews, and find where people talke about the mechanics, as well.

It's a concentrated resource for doing exactly the kind of research you probably should be doing.

Comment: OK didn't know of http://boardgamegeek.com/browse/boardgamemechanic  (boardgamegeeks hurts my eyes `_´ ) Got any other good resources?

Comment: For boardgames, not so much. For RPG design, there's RPGGeek.com and [The Forge (indie-rpgs.com)](http://indie-rpgs.com). And I never said it was pretty... just useful. (Tho' I have gotten used to it over the years.)

Answer (score 2):

There is also a list at Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_mechanics.

Comment: When I started to build my game over 1.5y ago, that wikipedia page almost didn't exist! :)

Comment: Is it worth posting a few examples you think are good?

Comment: I'm kinda taking note of what Pat Ludwig said when he edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fairly notable site [Three Hundred Mechanics](http://www.squidi.net/three/index.php) which you can visit for some inspiration, although it doesn't quite have 300 yet and is not specific to boardgames.

Comment: Thanks prusswan much. The http://www.squidi.net/three/index.php is very helpful

Comment: That's a great page, but what are listed are not game mechanics.  *(Game mechanics describe the actions players can take, gameboard constraints, and token values and interactions, among other things, but in no universe are "sniper buddies" or "sim game engine" game mechanics;)*